# How to implement security trimming with a website with multiple folders and multiple web.config files?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, active-directory

I have a website that has highly granulised access and hence requires many web.config files. The problem is I would like to trim the menu so that only certain users will have access to certain folders. I have enabled trimming and setup roles in the sitemap, however when I access the page the menu is not show, as I am authorized to view the default page which is not in a subfolder.
When I type the url of a page in sub folder's I have access.

How should I handle this:

1. A site map for each web.config file - don't know how this will work
2. Removing the sub web.config file to only use a single one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a site map for each web.config file.  When using the sitemap with a menu control and SitemapDataSource, ASP.NET will determine whether you have access to each page named in the sitemap through your configured MembershipProvider and/or RoleProvider, and if you do have access, the sitemap entry will be displayed in the Menu.

Note, that if you do not have access to all of the parents of an item in the sitemap, you will not be able to see that item.  You can configure your SitemapDataSource with StartingNodeUrl to change where the root of the Menu is set within the sitemap.

As far as why you don't see the default page in your Menu, if you can access the default page via entering the URL directly then the problem is most likely that you do not have the Menu or SitemapDataSource set up properly.  For help with that, see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227441.aspx  and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.menu.aspx#binding_to_data

If you need additional guidance I suggest you try to narrow down the exact cause of the issue, since Membership, Roles, Sitemaps and Menus are a pretty broad set of topics and there are tons of pitfalls that may occur.  Get your Menus up and running without security trimming, and verify that Membership and Roles are working properly before you try to link the two.

Comment: Thanks pseudocoder, the problem was that in the sitemap the first node did not have a url, if you change that to:                     <siteMapNode url="~/" title="Home" description="">

Answer (score 0):

you can use MembershipUser, RoleManager classes and  regsql.exe tool to generate your database of security.

Or create specific library of security with IPrincipal and IIdentity.

Answer (score 0):

Answered my question found solutions here:
[ASP Forums](http://forums.asp.net/t/1400899.aspx/2/10)

All that needed to be done was to make sure the top node in the sitemap had a url.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<siteMap xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/AspNet/SiteMap-File-1.0" >
      <siteMapNode **url="~/"** title="Home" description="">
      <siteMapNode title="Home" url="~/Default.aspx"/>
      <siteMapNode title="About" url="~/About/About.aspx" />
      <siteMapNode title="Lists" url="~/Lists/Lists.aspx" />
  </siteMapNode>
  </siteMap>
```

Note this line: